# text over imported svg with fabricjs

Tags: svg, fabricjs

I'm importing several svgs that are all created from the same image and layered on top of each other.  I would like to add text centered over a certain svg/textarea path.  And then scale textarea to fit the text provided with a min size.  And ive confused myself. I have no idea anymore? I deleted everything and started over direction would be very helpful.  Heres what i got.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/1-man.svg', function(objects, options) {
var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});

fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/1-man-cutout.svg', function(objects, options) 
{
var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});

fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/textarea.svg', function(objects, options) {
var obj2 = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
canvas.add(obj2).renderAll();
});

var text = new fabric.Text("Hello", {
fontFamily: 'ubuntu',
fontSize: 300,
textAlign: "center",
});

canvas.add(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Brain was dead i suppose.... took about a min this morning..  Ill keep it for a lesson on sleeping on it.

```
text.set('left', (objects[0].width - text.width)/2);
text.set('top', objects[0].top + 5);
canvas.add(obj2, text).renderAll();
```